# What is wrong with the spacing after this macro?

Tags: macros, xetex, pdftex

I'll go straight to the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mymacro{\MakeUppercase{this is my macro}}
\begin{document}
Foo \mymacro bar.
\end{document}
```

In my understanding, this should produce `Foo THIS IS MY MACRO bar.`, but instead I get `Foo THIS IS MY MACRObar.`, using both `xelatex` and `pdflatex`.

What is wrong with the macro above?

Comment: Why is that wrong? Spaces after macros are gobbled.

Comment: TeX ignores spaces after control sequences (commands), so if you type `\mymacro bar` or `\mymacro      bar` TeX will print `THIS IS MY MACRObar`. This is because if it didn't ignore spaces, it wouldn't know that what `\mymacrobar` is. If you want spaces after control sequences you can use `\mymacro\ bar` or `\mymacro{} bar` or use `xspace` as Bernard suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\xspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\newcommand\mymacro{\MakeUppercase{this is my macro}\xspace}


\begin{document}

Foo \mymacro bar.

\end{document}
```

[image]